# Why 2 classes Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl and Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl for same purpose?

Tags: magento2, php, curl

Magento Framework has 2 classes for Curl operations:

[\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Adapter\Curl](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Adapter/Curl.php) and

[\Magento\Framework\HTTP\Client\Curl](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.3-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php)

What is specific use-case for each as both are capable of doing same job ?

Answer (score 1):

**NOT THE ACTUAL ANSWER**

- Both classes are curl based wrapper classes.
- Tasks of the both classes remains the same such as connecting, writing, reading and closing connection to the server but in different way.

[Adapter CURL](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Adapter/Curl.php)

- Used as connector for `Zend_Http_Client` which has a internal framework - dependency on request type and response.
- Common method for **GET/POST/DELETE/PUT**
- First writes the request to the remote server using `write()` method and read the response using `read()` method.

[Client CURL](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php)

- Class to work with HTTP protocol which directly calls curl lib, no dependency on Framework Zend or Laminas.
- Different method for GET/POST, separate methods available `get()` and `post()`
- For other methods(PUT/DELETE) one has to trigger - method `makeRequest()`

I would say to implement the code using [Client CURL](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/2.4-develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/HTTP/Client/Curl.php) class only.